# How to Decode Transaction Input Data using Etherscan API in Python

Tags: etherscan, python

am trying to decode the Transaction Input Data using Etherscan API in Python, I tried different answers on this, but still can't do it. Maybe someone can Help me figure it out, my Code so far:

```
transactions_url = "https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x7666ca32ef844ff435506568f66d6de6792e8425&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey={myApiKey}"
response = get(transactions_url)
data = response.json()["result"]
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x["timeStamp"]))

for tx in data:
    inputdata = tx['input']
    print(inputdata)
```

My input Data is

```
 inputdata = 0x246bb536000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023404b7778c00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000064
```

I want this to be Decoded into:

```
#   Name    Type    Data
0   _satoshiAmount  uint256 38759051000000
1   _duration   uint256 100
```

Comment: to do that, for each transaction, you need the ABI of smart contract that the transaction interacted with.

Comment: thanks, do you have any example how to bind the abi of smart contract in this example please?

Comment: different transactions interact with different smart contracts. to get the ABI for a specific smart contract, you can also use the Etherscan API.

Comment: once you have the ABI, there's plenty of examples how to decode the Tx data using the ABI.

Comment: thanks for your answers, but I posted this question because I didn't find any example that explains it, tried different examples but none worked, i don't want to use infura or any other 3rd party api, wanted to solve it only with Etherscan API

Comment: I wouldn't give much hope your question will be answered as it's posted here, it's basically a programming project that should be a paid work if you want this to be implemented. suggest that you reduce the scope of your question and/or clarify what aspects you get stuck in.

Answer (score 2):

It's not perfect, but it'll get you the data you're looking for without needing to connect to a provider node. Answer edited to retrieve the ABI from Etherscan in the code.

```py
import json
from requests import get
from web3 import Web3
from other_file import ETHERSCAN_API_KEY

ADDRESS = "0x7666ca32ef844ff435506568f66d6de6792e8425"

abi_url = f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address={ADDRESS}&apikey={ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}"
abi_response = get(abi_url)
abi_str = abi_response.json()["result"]
abi = json.loads(abi_str)

w3 = Web3()
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=ADDRESS, abi=abi)

transactions_url = f"https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address={ADDRESS}&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey={ETHERSCAN_API_KEY}"
response = get(transactions_url)
data = response.json()["result"]
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x["timeStamp"]))

for tx in data:
    inputdata = tx['input']
    try:
        _function_object, function_params = contract.decode_function_input(inputdata)
        print(function_params)
    except:
        print('unable to decode')
```

This will print out dicts of the data you're looking for. You can format it as you like from there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I tried the code but I am having problems with Importing from web3 import Web3, I get the following Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Web3' from partially initialized module 'web3' (most likely due to a circular import)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your answer @pacrob, I changed my Code according to your answer. I got rid of that circular Import error, by changing the name of the .py file into "bla.py", then I run into an Address Checksum Error, I fixed that by adding w3.to_checksum_address(ADDRESS):

```
>     w3 = Web3()
>     dbAddress = w3.to_checksum_address(ADDRESS)
>     contract = w3.eth.contract(address=dbAddress, abi=abi)
```

Now everything is working. Great thanks